# DynamoDB requires all fields for ExclusiveStartKey on GSI, why?

Tags: pagination, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to implement a cursor-based pagination using DynamoDB (definitely not easy to do pagination in DynamoDB...) using a query request using `ExclusiveStartKey`.

My table index is made of an "id", while I have a GSI on "owner" (partition key) and "created_at" (range key).

I can easily retrieve the 10 first records using a `query` request, by specifying the GSI index and using the "owner" property.

However, on next requests, the `ExclusiveStartKey` only works if I specify the THREE elements from both indices (so "id", "owner" AND "created_at").

While I understand for "id", and "owner" as those are both partitioned key and are needed to "locate" the record, I don't see why DynamoDb requires me to specify the "created_at". This is annoying because this means that the consumer must not only submit the "id" as cursor, but also the "created_at".

As DynamoDb could find the record using the "id" (which is guarantees unique), why do I need to specify this created_at?

Thanks

Comment: If you only provide the `id` and the `owner` attributes, how would DynamoDB know from where to start processing items? You need to specify the exact item from where you want to continue your query, since `created_at` is one of the primary keys of the item, you have to specify it.

Comment: By using the id ? the id being the table partition key it's guaranteed to be unique it can used this info to know where to continue no?

Comment: In DynamoDB, an item's primary key is a combination of the hash (partition) key and the range (sort) key. If you didn't specify the latter, then your hash key will be the primary key. So, your table's primary key is the `id` attribute. But... **remember you are querying on a GSI!**. You no longer respond to the table's primary key, but to the **index primary key**! Your index primary key is the tuple `owner-created_at`, so you'll have to know **both** values to reference a specific item within the index.

Comment: As an extra comment, please note that [GSI primary keys can be duplicated](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html) (the keys don't have to be unique). So the table's primary key `id` is also required, as `owner-created_at` may not be enough to represent a single item in your table.

Comment: I don't know the answer, and am about to embark on a similar task myself, so I just want to continue the conversion, if possible. In the @MichaelGallego 's post, it looks like 'id' is the primary key of the table? Which means an item should be uniquely identifiable by 'id'. Logically, it seems possible to identify the last evaluated key using just 'id' regardless of whether querying on the table of a gsi. Does this make sense?

Comment: @MichaelGallego If keys are not unique then is there any way to paginate? I meant since gsi is not unique, we may get same key values as lastEvaluatedKey, so how can we proceed with this?

Answer (score 2):

GSI primary keys are not necessarily unique. Base table keys are necessary to answer the question, "For a given owner and creation date, up to which id did I read in this page?". Put another way, you could have multiple items with the same owner and creation date.

Comment: If keys are not unique then is there any way to paginate? I meant since gsi is not unique, we may get same key values as lastEvaluatedKey, so how can we proceed with this?

Answer (score 1):

In my testing, querying a gsi on a table resulted in a last evaluated key with all the item properties (essentially gsi key + table key). I needed to add all elements of the last evaluated key to the next request as exclusive start key to get the next page. If I excluded any elements of the last evaluated key in the next request, I received an exclusive start key error.

The following request:

```
aws dynamodb query --table-name MyTable --index-name MyIndex --key-condition-expression "R = :type" --expression-attribute-values '{\":type\":{\"S\":\"Blah\"}}' --exclusive-start-key '{\"I\":{\"S\":\"9999\"},\"R\":{\"S\":\"Blah\"},\"S\":{\"S\":\"Bluh_999\"},\"P\":{\"S\":\"Blah_9999~Sth\"}}' --limit 1
```

Resulted in the following response:

```
{
    "Items": [
        {
            "I": {
                "S": "9999"
            },
            "R": {
                "S": "Blah"
            },
            "S": {
                "S": "Bluh_999"
            },
            "P": {
                "S": "Blah_9999~Sth"
            }
        }
    ],
    "Count": 1,
    "ScannedCount": 1,
    "LastEvaluatedKey": {
        "I": {
            "S": "9999"
        },
        "R": {
            "S": "Blah"
        },
        "S": {
            "S": "Bluh_999"
        },
        "P": {
            "S": "Blah_9999~Sth"
        }
    }
}
```

If I left off some elements of the last evaluated key, for example (same request as above minus the table partition/sort keys):

```
aws dynamodb query --table-name MyTable --index-name MyIndex --key-condition-expression "R = :type" --expression-attribute-values '{\":type\":{\"S\":\"Blah\"}}' --exclusive-start-key '{\"I\":{\"S\":\"9999\"},\"R\":{\"S\":\"Blah\"}}' --limit 1
```

I get the following error:

```
An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the Query operation: The provided starting key is invalid
```